# use c++ 11 constexpr for std::map initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I want to initialize a std::map with the keys being a `constexpr`. Consider the following C++11 MWE:

```
#include <map>
using std::map;

constexpr unsigned int str2int(const char* str, const int h = 0) {
    return !str[h] ? 5381 : (str2int(str, h + 1) * 33) ^ str[h];
}

const map<unsigned int, const char*> values = {
    {str2int("foo"), "bar"},
    {str2int("hello"), "world"}
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

While the code compiles which recent clang and gcc, the resulting binary will contain the strings of the key type:

[image: C String Literals]

Why are the keys contained in the binary even though they are used as constexpr's? Any way to work around this behavior?

Of course the map initialization will occur at runtime. But shouldn't the values in the binary be replaced with the constexpr's at compiletime?

Note: This is of course a simplified example. I know there are different *boost* structures which may be more suitable for this use case. I'm especially interested in **why** this is happening.

[Edit]

The behavior occurs no matter if optimizations are enabled or not.
The following code compiles with *bar* being the only user defined string in the string table:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

constexpr unsigned int str2int(const char* str, const int h = 0) {
  return !str[h] ? 5381 : (str2int(str, h + 1) * 33) ^ str[h];
}

int main() {
  string input;
  while(true) {
    cin >> input;
    switch(str2int(input.c_str())) {
      case str2int("quit"):
      return 0;
      case str2int("foo"):
      cout << "bar" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

To verify the results I was using a small shell script

```
$ for x in "gcc-mp-7" "clang"; do 
  $x --version|head -n 1
  $x -lstdc++ -std=c++11 -Ofast constexpr.cpp -o a
  $x -lstdc++ -std=c++1z -Ofast constexpr.cpp -o b
  strings a|grep hello|wc -l
  strings b|grep hello|wc -l
done

gcc-mp-7 (MacPorts gcc7 7.2.0_0) 7.2.0
       1
       0
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)
       1
       0
```

Comment: constexpr means that the compiler can use the results during compile time. But it did not mean, that all evaluations must be done during compile time. C++ lacks the possibility to force compile time evaluation which is terrible. Some compilers complains with "expression to complex"...

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations? [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/AzZeMg) doesn't have the keys in the resulting assembly.

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: @tambre I do only use it to keep MWEs clean and clear ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this thread isn't really fresh, but to stick to c++11 is still required sometimes :|

how about using a constexpr function to set the keys:

```
constexpr int makeKey(const char* s) { // c++ refused 'auto' here
  return str2int(s); // using str2int from above
}

const std::map<unsigned int, const char*> values = {
    {k0, "bar"}, // these require another declaration (see above) 
    {k1, "world"}, 
    {makeKey("its"), "me"} // this initialization is 'single source'
};
```

'single source' keys simplify the maintenance of such maps once they become bigger ...

My small test program

```
...

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  for(int i(1);i<argc;++i)  {
    const std::map<unsigned int, const char*>::const_iterator cit(values.find(str2int(argv[i])));
    std::cout << argv[i] << " gets " << (cit==values.cend()?"nothing":cit->second) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

works fine and does not contain any of the key strings if compiled with gcc 7.5 using

```
--std=c++11 -O0
```

Answer (score 4):

Declaring only as const is not enough. The strings are included in the binary because:

```
const map<unsigned int, const char*> values
```

is const, but not constexpr. It will run 'str2int' when your program starts, not at compile time. Being const will only guarantee you that it will not allow further modifications, but makes no compile time compromises.

It seams you're searching for the Serge Sans Paille's Frozen constexpr containers -- https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen

Although I don't know if it will work on C++11, if you want performance gains, it definitely worths a try.

You can create maps that are hashed at compile time and will give you the additional benefit of producing a perfect hash function -- allowing all keys to be accessed in O(1) time (constant time).

It is a very competent substitute for gperf indeed.

Clang and GCC, currently, impose a limit on the number of keys you are able to process at compile time. Producing a map with 2048 keys turned out OK on my 1G RAM VPS only with clang. GCC is currently even worse and will eat all your RAM much sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Older thread, but you could also use C++ 17 compatible *constexpr hash-map*: [constexpr-hash-map](https://github.com/karel-burda/constexpr-hash-map).

This is essentialy a header-only hash-map-like structure made by myself in order to faciliate construction and retrieval (including lookup) in compile time in *constexpr* context.

The library has got specialization for the `const char*` to be able to compare keys in compile-time, so it would work for the main question.

Comment: Linking to your own library in an answer is ok, but in such case it's better to explicitly disclose your affiliation. Also, links are supplements to answers (and often are beneficial for their quality), which should nevertheless include explanations/solutions/examples within the answer body itself. Please [edit] your answer to include some explanation (in particular, how your library works). You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce with neither g++ (trunk) or clang++ (trunk). I used the following flags: `-std=c++1z -Ofast`. I then checked the contents of the compiled binary with `strings`: neither `"foo"` or `"hello"` were there.

Have you compiled with optimizations enabled?

Regardless, your use of `str2int` does not force compile-time evaluation. In order to force it, you can do:

```
constexpr auto k0 = str2int("foo");
constexpr auto k1 = str2int("hello");

const map<unsigned int, const char*> values = {
    {k0, "bar"},
    {k1, "world"}
};
```

Comment: I tried what you are saying, and it seems (strangely) that the `--std=C++1z` options fixes the code for me as well. Unfortunately - as stated in the question - I'm required to use C++11 for a certain project where the issue occurs. Any ideas how to fix it for C++ 11?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `-Ofast` that "fixes" the code?

Comment: yes, I tried it again using gcc 7.2.0 and clang-802.0.38 on macOS 10.13.1. Both omit the key strings iff I use `--std=C++1z`

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your issue using `--std=c++11 -O2` in GCC 7.2, clang 5.0 or MSVC 17.

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/g/ALPznC)

Are you building with debug symbols on (`-g`)? That could be what you're seeing.

Comment: strange, please see the bottom of my edit how I tested this. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: What if you try `-O2`? What does `objdump -sghCd` output?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<unsigned int x>
using kuint_t = std::integral_constant<unsigned int, x>;

const map<unsigned int, const char*> values = {
  {kuint_t<str2int("foo")>::value, "bar"},
  {kuint_t<str2int("hello")>::value, "world"}
};
```

that should force compile time evaluation.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) it is a bit less verbose:

```
template<unsigned int x>
using kuint_t = std::integral_constant<unsigned int, x>;
template<unsigned int x>
kuint_t<x> kuint{};

const map<unsigned int, const char*> values = {
  {kuint<str2int("foo")>, "bar"},
  {kuint<str2int("hello")>, "world"}
};
```

and in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
template<auto x>
using k_t = std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x>;
template<auto x>
k_t<x> k{};

const map<unsigned int, const char*> values = {
  {k<str2int("foo")>, "bar"},
  {k<str2int("hello")>, "world"}
};
```

it works with most primitive type constants without a type-specific version.